# Redirect to last visited page (stored in a cookie)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, cookies, httpcookie

In our MVC application we want the user, after he is logged in, to be redirected to the page he visted last in a previous session.

What is a good approach for achieving this?

I am thinking of an `httpmodule-->begin request or via the global.asax`

And at which point in the requestprocess should I put the logic to check whether the cookie exists and do the redirect?  In the `Application.init`?

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why you are making simple thing to complex? just check in login button click event.

Comment: Waqas is right.  Doing it in the action corresponding to the login button click would be the way to do it.

Comment: @Waqas, @Naraen Both of you are wrong. There does not exist button click event in mvc

Comment: @archil, you are right, but there must be some view method where user name and password is being checked through db.

Comment: Can you provide your process flow? As in 1. user accesses our site 2. goes to login screen (auto/manual) 3. logs in... etc. This will make it possible for us to analyse what you're doing wrong. Your redirection **should definitely be in controller action** in terms of *RedirectToSomething*... So you are doing something wrong here.

Comment: @HerbalMart: When you say: "After he's logged in" do you mean the next time he visits (first request) or after some time he's been here as anon user and then logs in? Each scenario would have to work in a completely different way.

Comment: Yes only on the first request of a session i woud like to do the redirect.

All of our controllers inherit from the controller called: "Application controller. This application conteroller contains a method "OnAuthorization". Should that be the place to place the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, there is no event on click. However, there is a much simpler soluction, MVC handles form submits and redirects quite well. To store the last visited URL, you could use an [action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) on your controller. Then to handle the redirect, create two Login functions. One handles the GET request, the other the POST request. In the POST request, after having verified authentication, retrieve the URL (or action) from the cookie and redirect the user.

It would be something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (authenticated)
    {
        //get cookie information
        HttpCookie cookie;
        cookie = Request.Cookies["StoredURLFromLastSession"];
        String StoredURLFromLastSession = cookie.Value;

        //Choose one of these redirect methods
        //returns to a hard coded URL
        //return Redirect(StoredURLFromLastSession);

        //redirects to a route (using routes created in global.asax
        //return RedirectToRoute(StoredURLFromLastSession);

        //redirects to a specific action/controller
        //return RedirectToAction(StoredURLFromLastSession);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: All of our controllers inherit from the controller called: "Application controller. This application conteroller contains a method "OnAuthorization". Should that be the place to place the logic?

Comment: @HerbalMart, I wouldn't recommend that. The Code example above already handles the login event. You have only one login action, and during that action, after you verify authentication, you redirect the user. Using the onauthenticate would mean you use [authorize] attribute not necessary how its meant to be used. The idea of creating your attribute is to keep track of the last URL the user accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [custom action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) that saves the currently requested URL to the cookie. Then check for the cookie value in your login action method and redirect if necessary.

In doing this you could decorate only the controllers and actions that you want that are potential entry points. e.g. not actions that return partial views etc.